# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class - how to fix it?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a very basic and yet annoying issue. I created new activities and pass the intent to move to them. Yet when I communicate the two:
MainMenu and EventCreationActivity, I get the following error:

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.mysampleapp.EventCreationActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

When I run the activities separately they work perfectly. 
Here is the code of MainMenu

```
   package com.mysampleapp;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

//import com.amazon.mysampleapp.R;

public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    //public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.mysampleapp.MESSAGE";
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, EventCreationActivity.class);
    Button newEvent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        newEvent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_event_button);

        newEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }



}
```

And manifest:

```
   <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LogInActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_log_in"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu"

            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <!--android:parentActivityName=".LogInActivity"-->
            <!--<meta-data-->
                <!--android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"-->
                <!--android:value="com.mysampleapp.LogInActivity" />-->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainDrawerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_drawer"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <!--<meta-data-->
                <!--android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"-->
                <!--android:value="com.mysampleapp.MainMenu" />-->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EventCreationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_event_creation"

            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <!--android:parentActivityName=".MainMenu"-->
            <!--<intent-filter>-->
                <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->
                <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />-->
            <!--</intent-filter>-->
            <!--<meta-data-->
                <!--android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"-->
                <!--android:value="com.mysampleapp.MainMenu" />-->
        </activity>
```

As you see, I commented some stuff in the Manifest file, but it did not help. I also looked other, similar questions and they did not help.

Thanks in advance,
John

Comment: show us EventCreationActivity

Comment: create your intent inside the button onclick

   newEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, EventCreationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

Comment: make sure your package defition in manifest is correct. `package="com.mysampleapp"'` . After this , you will have to have all activity classes in this package. So in your current exception case, make sure your `EventCreationActivity` is inside package `com.mysampleapp` . Provide `EventCreationActivity` class and full `manifest` if it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're instantiating the intent before the activity has gone through its life cycle methods. This means that the `Context` that you pass in to the `Intent` constructor is not valid.

Typically, the intent is created right before you use it:

```
newEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, EventCreationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't do it, as it then can't resolve "this" as the activity cannot be found

Comment: @JohnLeszcz try using `MainMenu.this` instead of `this`

Answer (score 5):

Solution is in your question

```
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

use full package name with class like this in your Manifest

```
android:name="com.mysampleapp.MainMenu"
```

Comment: I did this. I still get the same error. I did it for both MainMenu and EventCreationActivity.

Answer (score 1):

John, have you tried the full Activity name com.mysampleapp.MainMenu? Do this for all activities: your.package.ActivityName.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.mysampleapp.MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!--android:parentActivityName=".LogInActivity"-->
        <!--<meta-data-->
            <!--android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"-->
            <!--android:value="com.mysampleapp.LogInActivity" />-->
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these steps, you will definitely solve this problem:

1) Go To File.
2) Click on Invalidate Cache/Restart
3) Now go to AndroidManifest.xml and most probably you are not shown 
RED sign on your activity. If you see the RED on your activity then remove it and again type the name of the activity with packagename.

Answer (score 0):

Newbie here. I added the name of my 2nd java class to my AndroidManifest.xml, just above the  and right below the . Now I can run my application on the emulator instead of having the "apps keep closing" error. Im not quite sure why it worked though. Got the idea from above ^ @ikkarion.

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity2"
android:exported="true"/>
```